# How to safely remove arduino nano from breadboard?

Tags: arduino-nano, breadboard, capacitors

I did some prototyping with arduino nano in breadboard. And then after i done with the design, I was gonna implement it in a printed pcb so i need to remove the nano from breadboard. And this is when the disaster happened.

The board is kinda hard to pull by hand, so i use a long-thin screwdriver in the gutter to pull the nano up (just like i did many times to dip ICs with no problem). And successfully detached the nano from breadboard and also broke the tantalum under the nano in the process. So the question is:

1. How do you usually remove the nano board from breadboard safely? And
2. The tantalum i broke is 4.7uF smd. I can't find any 4.7uF tantalum in nearby shops, but i have electrolyte caps rated 4.7uF 16v. Can i use it for replacement?

Comment: Use long and wide screwdriver. put the tip under the board. Do not pull! Gently twist the screwdriver. After few millimeters do the same from the other side. After several such operations nano will be free with no pins bent, and no hardware damaged. For additional safety substitute screwdriver with something plastic.

Comment: What you really want is one of the long black plastic spudgers. Metal screwdrivers are asking for trouble. Plastic will flex more than the components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do you usually remove the nano board from breadboard safely? And

If you can't remove it by hand (grip it lengthwise and ease up each end with your finger / thumb levering against the breadboard) then you need a lever. The best is a plastic spudger, such as this:

[image]

The plastic will flex rather than damage the Arduino. Using a screwdriver can, as you have noticed, damage the Arduino.

> The tantalum i broke is 4.7uF smd. I can't find any 4.7uF tantalum in nearby shops, but i have electrolyte caps rated 4.7uF 16v. Can i use it for replacement?

Sure. All that is, is a reservoir capacitor on the USB input. The value isn't super-critical, as long as the voltage is above 5V. It's not, strictly speaking, even needed. You can just remove it completely and clean up the pads to ensure there's no shorts. The board should still work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem but what I had done was, I pressed the breadboard with my leg and used my all fingers to grip the nano and pulled it with my full force and then it is done. And no parts were damaged and id you lost any part you can search on https://octopart.com/ .

Comment: And if you just broken the whole you need to buy a new one. Or if not follow my answer.